Figure for IEEE Access submission
I am in the process of submitting an article to IEEE Access and they use a different syntax to present figures that the one I am used to with \begin{figure}... \caption.... Their template uses
\Figure[t!](topskip=0pt, botskip=0pt, midskip=0pt){fig1.png}
{Magnetization as a function of applied field.
It is good practice to explain the significance of the figure in the caption.\label{fig1}}

I am trying to figure out how to use subfigures with this syntax. I tried using the caption package, but the document class ieeeaccess is not supported, and the format is altered. Anybody knows how to accomplish this?

Welcome to TeX.SX! I looked into the code of the class file (which can be found here), and the \Figure command directly places the argument into a \includegraphics. So, you can't really use subfigures directly. But you could create the complete figure (including the subfigures) as PDF and then include this here.

Hi Jasper, thanks for the suggestion. Is there any way to replicate the format from the template in a tool like Inkscape in terms of fonts and font sizes? Do you know where I could find the appropriate values for this from the template file?

I thought that you could create the figure using LaTeX actually. You could use the same document class in order to achieve consistency regarding the font etc.

Check if the Figure caption looks the same with or without the caption package.  So long as you don't try to change the caption format, you should be okay.
